# How can i use this line gsub(/\s+/, "")

Tags: ruby

I have this integer i want delete space and delete the +966

```
str = '+9660556546509'.gsub(/\s+/, "", "+966")

puts str
```

And this error show up

```
bundle exec ruby main. rb
main.rb:1:in gsub': wrong number of argumen
ts (given 3, expected 1..2) (ArgumentError)
from main.rb:1:in
<main>!
exit status 1
```

Comment: You don't need delete whitespaces, because they are absent in your string. Just `'+9660556546509'.delete_prefix('+966')`

Comment: Your example could be improved if you wish to delete both `'+966'` and any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
str = '+9660556546509'.gsub(/\s+/, '').gsub('+966', '')
```

Output

```
0556546509
```

Comment: Probably reverse order is better. For example for `'+9 660556546509'`. So it's better to delete whitespaces first

Comment: Oh yes. it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your string doesn't contain whitespaces, you don't need to delete them

To delete prefix, you can use [`String#delete_prefix`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix):

```rb
str = "+9660556546509"
str.delete_prefix("+966") # => "0556546509"
```

There is also bang version:

```rb
str.delete_prefix!("+966")
str # => "0556546509"
```

If your string includes white spaces, you can firstly delete them with [`String#delete`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-delete), and after that use `delete_prefix`:

```rb
str = " +9 66 055 654 65 09  "
str.delete(" ").delete_prefix("+966") # => "0556546509"
```

Answer (score 0):

One could write

```
" + 9  6 6 0556 546 509".gsub(/\+ *9 *6 *6| */, '')
  #=> "0556546509"
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/TNR3Mx4YWhmwEd)

I've assumed that newlines are not to be matched, which is why I've chosen to match spaces rather than whitespace characters (`\s`). If tabs should also be matched one could replace the space characters with `[ \t]` or `\p{Blank}`.

The regular expression can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*.

```
/
\+     # match '+'
[ ]*9  # match zero or more spaces followed by '9'
[ ]*6  # match zero or more spaces followed by '6'
[ ]*6  # match zero or more spaces followed by '6'
|      # or
[ ]*   # match zero or more spaces
/x     # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

When using this mode it is necessary to protect any spaces that are part of the expression. I've done this by enclosing each space in a character class but one could alternatively escape each space character (`\` ).